# Is there a message_difference implementation in protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net

Similar to how it is in the google C++ version 
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer

I am trying to implement a way to notify users what has changed and this seems like would be the best way to do it, if I am already using protobuf-net for serializing.

Comment: No, not currently. Would be happy to consider it, probably for 3.2

Comment: Great!! Should I add it as an issue to the project GitHub repository?

Comment: Please - that's the easiest way for me to track things